# Easy way to delete a git branch from php

Tags: php, git

I'm trying to create a GUI made in php + js to list all the local + remote git branches for any repo. I have everything working except the part when i try to run the git branch -D command.

Basically the command never gets executed and the response is an empty array.

My take is that it is trying to delete it with the apache user _www instead of my user.

I would love to make this open-sourced so i think it won't help to add the ssh key to my apache.

Ideas? Suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I take it you've seen the [libgit2-php](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git) bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in looking into PHP Git (PHP bindings for Git2).

**Reference**: https://github.com/libgit2/php-git

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: Hi, i've already looked at the lib, and rather not use it for this since i want it super lightweight, but if i don't find a solution i will def use it, thanks!